# Changing mkv to mp4 with a batch script

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, ffmpeg, containers

What I want the `.bat` to do is to "scan" the files, in this case, `.mkv`, looking for streams (if there's more than a video stream and an audio stream you might need a matroska file). If you have an audio stream and a video stream, let's change the files as there's no reason to use matroska.

Currently I have 10 seasons of a TV show, which I personally ripped from my own DVDs, and they are in `.mkv` format. But inside the `.mkv` there's only video and audio, the subtitles are separate.

The only reason I want to change `.mkv` to `.mp4` is that plex can't use `.mkv`.

The current code I have to remove metadata on all `.XXX` in the folder:

```
if not exist "%~dp1_temp" (
    goto foldercreate
    )
    else (
    goto continue
    )

:foldercreate
echo.
echo Created temp folder.
echo -
mkdir _temp
attrib _temp +h
set errorlevel=
:continue
for %%f in (*%~x1) do (
    title Fixing %%f...
    move "%%f" _temp >nul
    echo Currently fixing %%f...
    ffmpeg -xerror -hide_banner -i "%~dp1_temp\%%f" -map_metadata -1 -codec copy -map 0 "%~dp1%%f" -loglevel warning -stats
    if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
        pause
        )
    del "%~dp1_temp\%%f"
    echo -
    )
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    echo FFmpeg errored...
    pause
    )
echo All done! removing temp dir...
rmdir _temp /S /Q
timeout /t 2 /nobreak>nul


:eof
```

Comment: You appear to have posted a task, but not posted a question showing a specific issue with the supplied code, and which you require our assistance to fix. This site doesn't help you to perform a series of steps making up a task, so if you have a specific and reproducible issue with your code, you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65997197/edit) to make it clear and answerable. _If you have to wait until you're no longer intoxicated to do that, then do so, but please do not add that you're drunk, (now removed) to your question as an excuse for your failures._

Comment: Also:  "plex can't use .mkv"  Since when?

Comment: @AnonCoward PLEX can use .mkvs, but it can't stream it.